# How to declare 4.1.0-RC1 release of spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to declare 4.1.0-RC1 release of spring-data-elasticsearch

```
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/releases
```

I used the following repositories, but it doesn't seem to work

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch', version: '4.1.0-RC1'

        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:4.1.0-RC1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:4.1.0-RC1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch/4.1.0-RC1/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch-4.1.0-RC1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch/4.1.0-RC1/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch-4.1.0-RC1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:4.1.0-RC1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch/4.1.0-RC1/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch-4.1.0-RC1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch/4.1.0-RC1/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch-4.1.0-RC1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:4.1.0-RC1.
         > Could not get resource 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch/4.1.0-RC1/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch-4.1.0-RC1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch/4.1.0-RC1/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch-4.1.0-RC1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pull in Spring Data Elasticsearch in version 4.1.0-RC1, not the boot starter:

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-elasticsearch', version: '4.1.0-RC1'
```

It might be that you have to pull in a RC version of Spring Data Commons as well:

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-commons', version: '2.4.0-RC1'
```